# Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Tags: php, html, validation

I'm validating my pages through http://validator.w3.org/ and only 4 errors were found, but in the same statement. and is to do with the div classes inside the brackets. Can anyone please help?

Thank you so much.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

$(function(){
    $("#ContactForm").submit(function(){
        $("#submitf").value='Please wait...';

        $.post("process.php?send=comments", $("#ContactForm").serialize(),
        function(data){
            if(data.frm_check == 'error'){ 

                    $("#message_post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>ERROR: " + data.msg + "!</div>"); 
                    document.ContactForm.submitf.value='Resend >>';
                    document.ContactForm.submitf.disabled=false;
            } else {
                $("#message_post").html("<div class='successMessage'>Thank you. We'll be in touch shortly.</div>"); 
                $("#submitf").value='Send >>';
                }
        }, "json");

        return false;

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Easiest and fastest solution: Put your JS in separate files.

Comment: `<` has to be written as `&lt;` in HTML, when it is _not_ suposed to have its special meaning, but is meant as a normal character instead.

Comment: Read [XHTML media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/). Better yet, don't use XHTML, it is more trouble then it is worth.

Comment: @CBroe — That isn't true inside `<script>` elements … in HTML, but it is in XHTML … but browsers don't care if the Doctype says it is XHTML or HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XHTML 1.0 Recommendation itself says, in Compatibility Guidelines, [item C 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4): “Use external scripts if your script uses < or & or ]]> or --.” The reason is that by XHTML rules, `script` element content is parsed by normal rules, so those characters are or they may be markup-significant.

Using `&lt;` for `<` etc. would fix this as regards to processing XHTML by the book, including general XML processing. But you probably intend to throw your page at various web browsers, and they will generally not do such processing but will handle the page as if it were HTML, and then things would fail.